# oracle 11g sql query obtains every number from set of ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, integer, range

Help me, please!
I have a table T_RANGE having two columns A and B (both are integer data type).
Each row of this table means one range of integer numbers.
Here are test data:

```
A | B
______
10 | 12
23 | 25
51 | 55
```

I have to make one SQL query (Oracle 11g) obtaining each integer number from all ranges of T_RANGE table (It has to be one integer column in the result set).
For my test data described above the result should be

```
10
11
12
23
24
25
51
52
53
54
55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc849/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A, B ) AS
SELECT 10, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 51, 55 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1** Use a Recursive Sub-Query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE):

```
WITH cte ( a, b ) AS (
  SELECT A, B FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT A + 1, B FROM cte WHERE A < B
)
SELECT a FROM cte
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc849/3/0)**:

```
|  A |
|----|
| 10 |
| 23 |
| 51 |
| 11 |
| 24 |
| 52 |
| 12 |
| 25 |
| 53 |
| 54 |
| 55 |
```

**Query 2** Use a correlated hierarchical query:

```
SELECT n.COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT t.A + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY t.A + LEVEL - 1 <= t.B
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) n
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc849/3/1)**:

```
| COLUMN_VALUE |
|--------------|
|           10 |
|           11 |
|           12 |
|           23 |
|           24 |
|           25 |
|           51 |
|           52 |
|           53 |
|           54 |
|           55 |
```

Answer (score 2):

This hierarchical query worked for me:

```
select a + level - 1 num
  from (select rownum rn, a, b from t_range) 
  connect by a + level -1 <= b and prior rn = rn and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1106)</sup>**

Comment: Since `PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` is always true so you should be able to remove that clause and expect the query will work - however, without that undocumented black-magic (or another similar hack) the query does not work as expected.

Comment: @MTO = there's an explanation [on this Oracle Community thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535). I usually use `dbms_random.value` rather than `sys_guid()` but it can be any non-deterministic function I believe..

Answer (score 2):

One more way to produce a range of number, using XML DB functionality:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with t_range(a, b) as (
  select 10, 12 from dual
  union all select 23, 25 from dual
  union all select 51, 55 from dual
)
-- actual query
select x.n
from t_range t
cross join xmltable(
  'xs:integer($a) to xs:integer($b)'
  passing t.a as "a", t.b as "b"
  columns n number path '.'
) x;

         N
----------
        10
        11
        12
        23
        24
        25
        51
        52
        53
        54
        55

11 rows selected.
```

This supplied an XPath sequence by passing in the lower and upper bounds (which are presented as decimals, so have to be cast to integer), and returns the sequence values as a numeric column called `n`.

As always when there are multiple approaches, compare their performance with realistic data. Among other things the size of your actual ranges will have an affect on how fast they run, and what resources they consume, and even in extreme cases whether they will run at all.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the "calendar table" approach where we create a table containing a continuous sequence wide enough to cover all the values in your table.  Then, we can join this sequence table to your data table and generate the ranges:

```
WITH numbers AS ( 
    SELECT 0 AS Number 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Number + 1 
    FROM Numbers 
    WHERE Number + 1 <= 100
),
yourTable AS (
    SELECT 10 AS col1, 12 AS col2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 23, 25 UNION ALL
    SELECT 51, 55
)

SELECT *
FROM numbers t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Number BETWEEN t2.col1 AND t2.col2
ORDER BY
    t1.Number;
```

An improvement to the above might be to use dynamic data for the bounds of the CTE sequence.  But, if you are doing this in production, you might just hard code a range large enough to cover any expected value.  Or, you could create a separate bona fide table containing the full sequence.

Comment: This will fail if the range is wider than your magic number (100).

Comment: @MT0 I gave a caveat about that.  In production, if the OP uses this method (and I think a table would be better), I am assuming they would know the scope of the range ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle best practise is connect by to produce the numbers.
Additionally Number is a reserved word which shouldn't be used.

So the SQL from Tim is in Oracle:

```
WITH numbers AS ( 
    SELECT level nb     FROM dual connect by level <= 100
),
yourTable AS (
    SELECT 10 AS col1, 12 AS col2 from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 23, 25 from dual   UNION ALL
    SELECT 51, 55 from dual  
)
SELECT nb
FROM numbers t1, yourTable t2
where t1.nb BETWEEN t2.col1 AND t2.col2
ORDER BY t1.nb;
```

Comment: This will fail if the range is wider than your magic number (100).

Comment: Why is using connect-by rather than a recursive CTE 'best practice'?

Comment: Because it's faster to generate a small number (1000000) records. For 1.000.000 rows 0,5s vs 7s. For this example it's possible that if you start at a large number and have a small range recursive subquery factoring could be better